# Vulkan: dynamic buffer offset incorrectly out of range

Tags: vulkan

So I am using dynamic uniform buffers in Vulkan to upload the transformation matrix of a bunch of objects for each frame to one big buffer. I have two "virtual frames" with two descriptor sets that I alternate between the frames. They both use the same big buffer at different offsets. When I log all the values that I use to bind the buffer to the descriptor sets, all seems well. The two sets are updated with the following infos:

`VkDescriptorBufferInfo{ .offset = 0, .range = 704, .buffer = ... }`

`VkDescriptorBufferInfo{ .offset = 704, .range = 704, .buffer = ... }`

The buffer in question is `1408` bytes in size. I draw 11 objects each frame, where each object consumes 64 bytes for 1 4x4 floating point matrix (note 11 x 64 = 704, it all checks out). So the dynamic offsets I use increase with `64` bytes per draw call.

I have triple checked all my offsets, however Vulkan still throws this error on the second frame (with the bound buffer offset of 704), for any dynamic offset > 0:

> Validation Error: [ VUID-vkCmdBindDescriptorSets-pDescriptorSets-01979 ] Object 0: handle = 0x55cc0d782010, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; Object 1: handle = 0xa21a4e0000000030, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET; Object 2: handle = 0x2e2941000000001f, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0xa159a763 | vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(): pDynamicOffsets[0] is 0x40 which when added to the buffer descriptor's range (0x2c0) is greater than the size of the buffer (0x580) in descriptorSet #0 binding #0 descriptor[0]. The Vulkan spec states: For each dynamic uniform or storage buffer binding in pDescriptorSets, the sum of the effective offset, as defined above, and the range of the binding must be less than or equal to the size of the buffer (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.204.1/linux/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdBindDescriptorSets-pDescriptorSets-01979)

Except as far as I can tell this error literally contradicts itself. It says the dynamic offset of `0x40` (i.e. `64`), when added to the bound buffer's range of `0x2c0` (i.e. `704`) is greater than the size `0x580` (i.e. `1408`). Which it is not, `0x40 + 0x2c0 = 0x300` and `0x300 < 0x580`.

The actual effective offset within the buffer (ignoring its own base offset into the VkDeviceMemory object), as far as I'm aware, should be `704 + 64`, as the buffer is bound at 704 and the dynamic offset is 64. Which is still less than `1408`, the actual buffer's size.

Any clue as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok after an entire afternoon of debugging and searching, according to the Vulkan spec on VkDescriptorBufferInfo:

> range is the size in bytes that is used for this descriptor update, or VK_WHOLE_SIZE to use the range from offset to the end of the buffer.

and

> For VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC and VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER_DYNAMIC descriptor types, offset is the base offset from which the dynamic offset is applied and range is the static size used for all dynamic offsets.

`range` denotes the uploaded size, so for each offset that's only the size used for that draw call. I was giving it the range of the entire dynamic buffer. So range should be `64` not `704` :)